# Creating logo files for printing and web

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, color-spaces, digital-printing

My client has asked for their logo files, (the source file is vector AI created with Illustrator). He wants a file for the web/printing letterhead (online and paper invoices) and a vector file for the printing materials like marketing stuff and advertising (t-shirt, trifold, stickers and business cards ...).
What’s the best way to convert the original colours without changing them or ending up with a bad colour final result?

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of what kind of software you used (e.g. raster versus vector), and what format you did the artwork in, it's rather difficult to answer this. Please consider adding these details to your question.

Comment: Vector file created with adobe illustrator

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, use RGB for web, and home/office inkjet printing (with sRGB as the profile).

CMYK for professional digital/lithographic printing, or even Spot Pantone colours for lithographic printing/screen printing.

Some formats to give your client: Vector: PDF, SVG, EPS, and Raster: PNG, JPEG, CMYK TIFF.  That should just about cover everything they will ever need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I wonder if there’s any hex code database for the colours to be the same as possible in CMYK and also in RGB

Comment: All the online color converters provide the Hex, CMYK and RGB values for any hue. Even the new Google pop up converter if you search for color picker.